# Accounting for ties in combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics

In this problem, there is a race between 6, and then 7, horses.
These horses can tie, so how many different possibilities are there for each scenario?

I know that this is how you would start:
no ties - 6! (7! for the second problem)
all same - 1 possibility
and there would be factorials involved. I don't really know how to account for the ties.

EDITED: if I accounted for a tie between 2 horses, would I use C(6,2)?
How would I go about calculating the coefficients?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to set up a recursion based on the number of horses that tie for last place.  If you have $n$ horses, this number can be anything from $1$ to $n$.  The relevant recursion turns out to be

$$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}S(n-k)$$

where $S(n)$ is the desired number of outcomes, with $S(0)=1$ to get things started.  Thus

$$S(1)={1\choose1}S(0)=1\cdot1=1$$ 
$$S(2)={2\choose1}S(1)+{2\choose2}S(0)=2\cdot1+1\cdot1=3$$ 
$$S(3)={3\choose1}S(2)+{3\choose2}S(1)+{3\choose0}S(0)=3\cdot3+3\cdot1+1\cdot1=13$$

and so forth.  If you don't want to do the calculations to get to $S(6)$ and $S(7)$ yourself, you can find them at [A000670](http://oeis.org/A000670) in the OEIS.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try enumerating all the different scenario you can possibly have.

In the case when you have no tie, it is straightforward (and you got it).

For a tie between two horses, the tie could be in first place, **or** second, **or** third place, etc...

If you are allowing a tie between multiple horses, then you will have to take into account the tie between three horses, four horses and so on.

**Edit**: I will expand a bit more upon what I was to convey. They are probably easier way to find the answer to the problem, but here is another way.
Also pointed out by user **Barry Sipra**, this reasoning only takes into account for multiple ties.

If you have 6 horses racing with a possibility of ties (I will assume that more than two horses can be tied to a certain position).

**case 1: no tie**. In this case there is $6!$ possibilities.

**case 2: tie between two horses**. Since the order between the two horses that are tied does not matter, you can use a combination and obtain $6 \choose 2$ $\times 4!$. Since here you can have a tie for the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th place, you will have in the end $5\times$$6 \choose 2$ $\times 4!$ configurations.

To be more general, if you had $n$ horses and there is possibility for two of them to end up in a tie, you will have $$\underbrace{(n-\overbrace{2}^{\text{number of horses tied}}+1)}_{\text{number of positions to be tied in}}\times
\underbrace{{n\choose 2}}_{\text{the number of couple that can get in a tie}}\times\underbrace{(n-2)!}_{\text{# arrivals of horses not tied}}$$ different configurations.

**case 3: tie between three horses**. Using the same logic as above, you will have $4\times$$6\choose 3$$\times 3!$.

**case 4: tie between four horses**. You will get $3\times$$6\choose 4$$\times2!$.

**case 5: tie between 5 horses**. You will get $2\times$$6\choose 5$$\times 1!$.

**case 6: tie between all 6**. You will get $1\times$$6\choose 6$$\times 0!$.

For your final answer, you will sum the result you obtain from all the different cases namely:
$$
6!+5\times {6 \choose 2} \times 4!+4\times {6 \choose 3} \times 3! + 
3\times {6 \choose 4} \times 3!+2\times {6 \choose 5} \times 1! +1\times {6 \choose 6} \times 0!.
$$

If I did not make any mistake, you should get $3283$ ways.

Comment: I think its trickier than this.

Comment: @Omnitic, I expanded upon what I meant.

Comment: @ZanCoul, your answer disagrees with what the OEIS gives (the link is in my answer).  You are omitting multiple ties, e.g. two horses tie for first and another two tie for last place.

Comment: @Omnitic, that's right! I forgot to account for that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: that last part was due to @BarryCipra, who also answered the question correctly.

Comment: @Omnitic: fixed, thanks for pointing out. Since there is a better answer, should I delete what I have here, or leave it as log?